# How can I solve Android studio API platform

Tags: android-studio

When I create a new project in Android studio I chose 2.3 for API level but when the project installed in platform 4.0.0 it stopped! It works just in 5.0.0 to up!

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting. and the gradle of Module

Answer (score 0):

here is my gradle moudle code and there is no error!!`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.milad_admin.counter"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
```

}
`